# Jquery change multiple select buttons with a select button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change multiple select buttons's values with another select button.

Practically when someone select an option in the main select button, the other select buttons must change with that value.

**EDIT:** I added the code, the first is the main select button and after I select somethig there, it should change in the others.

```
<select class="select_format">
    <option value="0.49">9x13</option>
    <option value="0.59">10X15</option>
    <option value="0.99">13X18</option>
    <option value="1.20">15X21</option>
    <option value="2.60">20X30</option>
</select>

<select name="format[]" class="format_imgs">
    <option value="0.49">9x13</option>
    <option value="0.59">10X15</option>
    <option value="0.99">13X18</option>
    <option value="1.20">15X21</option>
    <option value="2.60">20X30</option>
</select>
<select name="format[]" class="format_imgs">
    <option value="0.49">9x13</option>
    <option value="0.59">10X15</option>
    <option value="0.99">13X18</option>
    <option value="1.20">15X21</option>
    <option value="2.60">20X30</option>
</select>
<select name="format[]" class="format_imgs">
    <option value="0.49">9x13</option>
    <option value="0.59">10X15</option>
    <option value="0.99">13X18</option>
    <option value="1.20">15X21</option>
    <option value="2.60">20X30</option>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to add your code to the question :)

Comment: The code is now added.

Comment: Now you forgot to add the JS code.... you know, we love to help, but we won't make it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't supply code here's a guess:

```
$(".myTriggerButton").on("click", function() {
      $(".buttonToChangeValue").each(function() { 
          this.value = "new value";  
       });
});
```

Comment: I added the code now, can you make some code for my example please?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.select_format').change(function(){

    $('.format_imgs').val( $(this).val() );

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7hno0ob8/1/

Comment: I added the code now, can you make some code for my example please?